# Make spark return tuple (StructType) from case expression without UDFs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking(did some tests without success) to return a tuple StructType from a case statement without using UDFs, is there any way to do it?

Use case is: we have 2 columns that depend on the same conditions in a CASE expression so we see 2 options:

- writing the same conditions twice but returning different column (undesired)
- writing the conditions once but returning 2 values on every WHEN, this could be via a tuple that we then split.

I know it can be done using a UDF but we avoid UDFs due to being treated as blackboxes by spark and hence they are not optimizable, so the question is: **is there any way to make a CASE statement return multiple values without using UDFS?**

Something similar to:

```
df = df.withColumn("tuple", expr(
"CASE WHEN <condition 1> THEN (value1,value2)
      WHEN <condition 2> THEN (value3,value4)
      ELSE (value5,value6)
"))

df = df.withColumn("col1",col("tuple")[0])
df = df.withColumn("col2",col("tuple")[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array`:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "tuple", 
    expr("""
        CASE WHEN <condition 1> THEN array(value1,value2)
             WHEN <condition 2> THEN array(value3,value4)
             ELSE array(value5,value6)
        END
   """)
)

df = df.withColumn("col1",col("tuple")[0])
df = df.withColumn("col2",col("tuple")[1])
```

But note that the arrays should all be of the same type, i.e. `value1`, `value3`, `value5` should have the same type, and `value2`, `value4`, `value6` should also have the same type.